# Define a constructor methods and assigning variables inside them

Tags: java, arrays, methods, constructor

I've post this question before, but it was not clear.

But now, I'll be more specific and explain my problem in detail.

It's project with 2 packages, the first package has two classes (Matrix, Operator) , I'll just focus on first class which is matrix

I have seven constructor functions/methods requirements for matrix class, but I'll post six of them here, and **I want to check if I write the code correctly or not for each constructor method of them** 
- **That's why I post this question here** -

Before the first constructor method , also I have to check if I write the correct code or not for these three field data members that I've to define it before all of the methods

field data members for Matrix class

(1) "data" - use a 2D array to store the values for all the elements, using "double".

(2) "rows" - defining the number of rows of the matrix, using "int".

(3) "cols" - defining the number of columns of the matrix, using "int".

This is my code for it:

```
      double [] []data; 
      int rows;
      int cols;
```

Is't correct, or I define it wrongly ?

Now is Matrix class methods:

the first constructor method :

(1) Constructor 1- empty arguments (default constructor). Assign 1 for both the row and column and 0.0 for all the elements.

And this is my code for it:

```
    Matrix() {
    rows = 1;
    cols = 1;
    data [rows] [cols] = 0.0;
    }
```

How about it ?

The second constructor method

(2) Constructor 2- two arguments (int, int), assigning the row and column properties with all the elements equal to 0

and this is my code:

```
    Matrix(int a, int b) {
     rows = a;
     cols = b;
     for(int i=0; i<=rows;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<=cols;j++)
            {
               data[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
  }
```

the third constructor method

(3) Constructor 3 (10%) - three arguments (int, int, double), assigning the elements with the third argument "double", which is an 2D array. You need to do some checking to make sure the input 2D array should have at least the same number of rows and columns as the first two input arguments. It is fine if the passed 2D array supports more data than the rows and columns needed. You can simply ignore those extra numbers. (Hint: to check the size of the array, use the "length" data member of an array object)

and this is my code for it :

```
   Matrix(int c, int d, double [] [] e){
    c = rows;
    d = cols;
    data = e;

    for (c = 0; c < e.length ; c++) {
         for (d = 0; d < e[0].length ; d++) {

             System.out.println(e[c][d]);            

         }
    }
  }
```

The fourth constructor method

(4) Constructor 4- three arguments (int, int, double). This is very similar to the "constructor 3". The only difference is the third argument, which is a 1D array. It is a bit tricky here that you need to convert the 1D into 2D yourself. We assume the elements in the 1D array is in row wise. e.g. a[] = {5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2}, if you store this array into a 3 x 2 matrix. It is like 5, 2, 3 for the first row, and 4, 3, 2 for the second row

and this is my code:

```
     Matrix(int c, int d, double [] f){
    c = rows;
    d = cols;
     double [] []v;     
    for (int i = 0, k=0; i < 4; i++){
          for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            v[j][i] = f[k++];
          }
    }
 }
```

the fifth constructor method

(5) void printMat() (10%) - print the matrix data row by row. e.g. if the matrix has data [2][3] = {5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2}, then this function will print it out on the console:

```
                                 5, 2, 3,

                                 4, 3, 2
```

and this is my code :

```
    void printMat(){

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length ; j++) {

             System.out.println(data[i]\n);          
            } 
         }
    }
```

The sixth constructor method

(6) void copyTo(Mat mat) (10%) - copy the value of current matrix to the input variable "mat". e.g. Mat a; Mat b; ...; a.copyTo(b); //b will be identical to a

this is my code

```
    void copyTo(Mat mat){
        Mat k;
        k.copyOf(mat);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: so much here to read :)

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why don't you test your code, by compiling it, and executing it? Every code snippet you posted has at least one bug, that you would find by simply executing it.

Comment: What is your specific question/problem? It's not our job to correct your homework assignment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has posted a number of unrelated queries within one question.  Please restrict to one query/question.  Also, it's not clear what your problems are with each query, be sure that the issues are clearly stated.

Comment: To add to this - you posted a problem and then a short snippet of your code.  You never state what does (or does not) work.  We're not going to debug your problems and then provide solutions.  That's your job.

Comment: Finally, this is not a place for code review (there are other sites for that)

Comment: "I've post this question before, but it was not clear." I wonder what the answers were before, and whether the "not clear" is referring to the question or the answers.

Answer (score 0):

1) and 2) You never allocate `data`. NullPointerException at runtime.

3) and 4) have same signature. Won't compile.

5) `println(data[i]\n)` is invalid syntax. Won't compile. Use `println(data[i])`.

6) `k` is unassigned. Won't compile.

Comment: All of which the OP could have discovered by invoking a compiler :(  BTW, the downvote(s) are/is not from me - enabling behavior is not downvotable.

Comment: @Satya No, I skimmed it. Too much text.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Very true, but you won't even need to compile it. Any IDE would have told OP before even saving and compiling. *<wishing>* SO should make it a requirement to use an IDE before being allowed to post Java questions.

Comment: For the down-voter: Thanks ;-) I know I shouldn't have answered, but I couldn't help myself seeing such glaring errors. My OCD won't allow it, and will accept the negative rep. *<bows>*

Comment: This is only a part of the bugs! In (1) for example, there should be an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if data was correctly instantiated.

Comment: @C.Champagne Well, I figured that the line would be *replaced* with the array allocation, since the array values would be `0.0` anyway. Of course, that is an assumption, and given the rest of the code, not a very good one, I do admit, but one error at a time. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas You are right. One error at a time. The answer would be longer than the question either :-)

Comment: You guys not serious to help the users, when I asked this question before you all said, it's not clear and be specific, and when I be specific you said too much text. Just say I don't wanna help. I just wanna see if my codes correct or not. first you all said post your codes and we ' will correct it, and now no one want help. Just close the question and thanks.  @Andreas

Comment: @faho0odywbas Don't ask 6 questions in one post. Ask 1 question, *if* you have a question. "How about it ?" is not a valid question. If you're just looking for code review, try posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. But why are you asking for code review, when it doesn't even compile? Fix your compile errors first, or if you have a question *about* a compile error, your question must include the error message.

Comment: @faho0odywbas As for your comment "I just wanna see if my codes correct or not". If you try to compile the code, and it fails, your code is obviously not correct, so that's not what you were trying to do. Or you could have figured it out for yourself by compiling, and not waste everybody's time, incl. your own.